# Why does "read -a" give out error "bad option -a"?

Tags: bash, read

I tried this command :

`read -a arr <<< "a b c"`

on centos, it runs well, but on kali (2023.2), it reports "read: bad option: -a"

I cannot find out why. Any help please?

Comment: Kali Linux nowdays uses `zsh` as the default user shell. So using `read -a` is not possible, instead use 'read -A': `read -A arr <<< "a b c"`

Comment: `-A`, same as in ksh or yash, consistent with `set -A` (`set -a` from the Bourne shell being for something else). Why bash chose to use `-a` instead when it added array support decades after other shells and otherwise copied the awkward array design of the Korn shell is beyond me...